# Webpage in Webview not displaying

Tags: android, android-emulator

the page says "webpage not available" in the emulator.  Ive tried chaning the wv.loadURL to load a simple yahoo.com page but i still get the same result.  However I am able to see the the layout and information in the .index file when i try the code below...any suggestions?

```
    package com.example.athletic_profile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the internet permissions required?

Comment: As AC said first check your permissions, and second are you sure the address has the "http://" prefix? If not you can add it to the start of the string at runtime or just update the urls in your Index.html